# How do I move a UIToolbar Item?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I am using a `UIToolbar` in iOS and am trying to get a new button to 'arrive' by sliding in from the right. Is there a way to directly access the 'position' of the button on the bar? I currently have a messy workaround that is getting close to the desired effect, but i was hoping there was a way to move them using Core Animation, so i could implement the 'EaseInEaseOut' type timing functions. Any ideas?

```
- (void) testPart1 {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0) target:self selector:@selector(testPart2:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:500] repeats:NO];
}

- (void) testPart2:(NSTimer*)sender {
    int countdown = [sender.userInfo integerValue];
    theSpace.width = 10+(int)countdown;
    itemTestButton.width = 49;
    itemTestButton.width = 50;
    countdown -= 5;
    if(countdown>0)
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.004) target:self selector:@selector(testPart2:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countdown] repeats:NO];
}
```

The premise here was using an `NSTimer` to change the width of a Fixed Space Bar Button item, and count down to zero. I found I had to change the width of an actual button to make it work, otherwise no 'animation' would occur. It's messy I know, someone must have a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a plain `UIView` as a subview of the `UIToolbar` that is rendered exactly as the bar button would be (you could get this by calling `renderInContext:` on an existing button) and then animate that view into the proper position.  In the completion block of that animation you could then set the real button and `removeFromSuperview` the animation view, and it will look indistinguishable to the user.